# How to setup an API server with no domain name

Tags: node.js, api, server, digital-ocean

I've been struggling to understand this because I don't quite know what to search for. Basically, I'm working on a simple node server that just works as an API that is to be consumed by a mobile application. I'm planning to deploy it to DigitalOcean but since I don't need a domain name because I don't have a website, how will I send the HTTP requests to the server? My guess is something related to the droplet's IP but that doesn't seem quite right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send requests to IP address and port from your mobile app. like `GET http://54.54.32.23:3000/user-newsfeeds/15`